# QFileSystemModel and QTreeView - strange behavior when resetting view

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

I wrote this on official forums of Qt, but it seems dead, so I am going to copy-paste it here.

I am writing small program for copying files. I use `QTreeView` and I have inherited from `QFileSystemModel`, so I was able to add checkboxes to every row in the `QTreeView`. I also use `setNameFilters` method connected with `QLineEdit`, so user can specify what file extensions he wants to display in the `QTreeView`. I have spotted the following behavior:

1) When I run the program and enter extensions to filter (without touching any node from the `QTreeView`) everything works fine and files with extensions I have provided are only displayed (and folders of course). When I change the extensions and the view is refreshed, on my `"C:/"` drive everything is updated and only new set of extensions is displayed. When I expand some other drive that I didn’t touch before, it also shows files correctly.

2) When I run the program and expand let say my `"C:/"` and `"D:/"` drives I see all directories and files (expected behavior). Then I write some extensions and the view is refreshed. I expand `"C:/"` drive and everything works fine, only files with extensions I have provided are displayed. Then I go to `"D:/"` drive and here is the problem. It displays all files. It ignores the filters I have provided. When I open the `"E:/"` drive that I have not opened before, the files are filtered correctly as in `"C:/"` drive.

I have concluded, that this behavior has something to do with `setRootPath` method, because for my `QTreeView` only in `"C:/"` drive the filters are working correctly. All other drives that were expanded before change of filters don’t work. Those not expanded work just fine.

The question is: How to get this working, so after user changes the filters and reset() method is fired, the whole `QTreeView` is refreshed and not only root path and not-expanded elements? Maybe there exists some root path that have all the drives as children and it will work as expected? Or maybe I should make some virtual folder in the `QTreeView` called `"MyComputer"` and set it to be a parent for all the drives? But how to get list of all the available drives?

I hope that what I wrote is clear for you and you can help me to get this working.

**Edit:**
Adding some code that is relevant. If you need more just ask.

```
//setting up the model and view
QString rPath = "C:/";
rTree_model = new TreeModel(this); //TreeModel inherits from QFileSystemModel
rTree_model->setRootPath(rPath);

ui->rTree->setModel(rTree_model); //applies the model for the qtreeview (ui->rTree)

//(...)

//action when extensions were provided by user
QString extensions = QString(ui->extensionBox->text()); //gets extensions provided by user
QStringList filters;
if(extensions.length() > 0) {
    filters = extensions.split(";", QString::SkipEmptyParts); //splits extensions provided with ';' as separator
    rTree_model->setNameFilters(filters); //applies filters
    ui->rTree->reset(); //resets the view
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code that would help us to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @Riateche Here you go.

Comment: What does TreeModel::reset() do? Is it just the default implementation?

Comment: @Phlucious, it is exactly this: [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtreeview.html#reset). And this is not method from the model, but from the qtreeview (element of GUI).

Comment: I have reproduced this error in Qt 4.8.2. I'll see if I can figure something out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your root path to My Computer instead of C:/. It seems to work with QFileSystemModel in Windows 7 x64 and Qt 4.8.2, but I can't guarantee anything for other platforms.

```
rTree_model = new TreeModel(this);
QString rPath = model->myComputer().toString();   //causes the QFileSystemWatcher to watch every drive?
rTree_model->setRootPath(rPath);

ui->rTree->setModel(rTree_model);
```

Comment: You are awesome! :) I knew it was something with that path, but I didn't know, that there exists a `myComputer()` method. I guess if I had more time I would find it eventually. Anyway, it works now and you get the bounty (in 14h, it cannot be done now). You have earned it! :)

Comment: Glad it worked! By the way, not sure which Qt forums you originally posted on, but I've had some success on qtcentre.org with my questions.

Comment: I've posted it on official forums at qt-project.org. Thanks for the advice, I'll take a look at this site. :)

Comment: You can just pass an empty string as root - the result is the same as fetching the "My Computer" name.